# .net compliant version control system that can be installed on a shared hosting (with no SSH/root Access)

Tags: version-control, shared-hosting, windows-hosting

I searched a lot in SO and other websites for a version control system that can be installed on a shared windows hosting that lets me create repositories for putting my project files on it and supply me with version control facilities but I did not find one. I looked to see whether I can install git, Mercurial or TFS in a shared hosting and I did not found any answer. I want to know if you know any system that can be installed on a shared windows hosting and please tell your recommendations if you have had an experience before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such a solution. But [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org) is a very good repo which provides free private repos.